# how to make renderText() only trigger by a button Rshiny

Tags: r, button, shiny, shinyapps

I have a question when using renderText() function when this text box is triggered by a button. The output Error only triggered by the button for the first time, but for the second or third time, I don't have to click the button, the error text already showed. I think it is really confusing. Here is my code:

```
library(DT)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$searchbutton, {
    if (input$id %in% df$ID) {
      data1 <-
        datatable({
          memberFilter <-
            subset(df, df$ID == input$id)
        }, rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't')) 
      
      output$decision <- DT::renderDataTable({
        data1
      })
      
    }
    
    
    else{
      
      output$Error<- renderText(if(input$id %in% df$ID || input$id==""){}
                                else{
                                  paste("This ID :",input$id,"does not exist")
                                })
      
      })
      
      
    }
    
  })
})
so the problem is in this renderText function, if I click the button more than once, the text box will updated automatically when I change the input even i did not click the button.

I guess this issue is because the text box has been triggered, it always 'rendering' the text box, so it did not need to trigger again, if there any solution can make this renderText box always been  triggered by button?
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could prepare minimal, reproducible example, so we could talk about your real or almost-real app, but I have prepared MRE for our discussion:

```
library(shiny)

ids <- 1:5


ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("id_to_check", "Id to check", value = 0),
    actionButton("check_id_btn", "Check"),
    textOutput("check_result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$check_id_btn, {
    if (input$id_to_check %in% ids) {

    } else {
      output$check_result <- renderText({
        paste0("This ID: ", input$id_to_check, " does not exist.")
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So we  have `ids` (from 1 to 5) and the Shiny app, in the server in `observeEvent` we check if the chosen `id` (from `numericInput`) exists in `ids` and if not, we display the user information that id doesn't exist.

Is this app shows the problem you see in your app? When you push "Check" button (and leave 0 as a id), text is displayed and then, when you change id, text - at least visually - changes and gives wrong results (e.g. if we change id to 1, then we should see any text output according to this part of code:

```
if (input$id_to_check %in% ids) {

    } else {
```

)

So the first thing is that:

- you should **never** nest objects which belongs to reactive context (`observe`, `reactive`, `render*`),it just won't work in expected way most of the time.

If you want to trigger `render*` only if the event occurs (like the button is pushed), then you can use `bindEvent()` function (from `shiny`):

```
library(shiny)

ids <- 1:5


ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("id_to_check", "Id to check", value = 0),
    actionButton("check_id_btn", "Check"),
    textOutput("check_result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$check_result <- renderText({
    if (!input$id_to_check %in% ids) {
      paste0("This ID: ", input$id_to_check, " does not exist.")
    }
  }) |>
    bindEvent(input$check_id_btn)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have removed `observeEvent()`, because I don't see the reason to leave it if we want just to display something, but I don't know your app, so maybe you need this, but do not nest anything which is reactive.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! This is the first time I heard about blinEvent(). However, I tried and think this doesn't work for my circumstances, because I use a ObserveEvent() so that I can make everything triggered by a search button. I just updated my code in my question, do you mind take a look into it when you are available? Thank you so much!!!!